# How to add new port number to nginx server?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I want to add new port number to nginx server or how to add new server block to nginx server.

Comment: You could always repeat the `server {}` block in `nginx.conf` or touch another file including `server {}` block. If you use a new file, make sure including it in `nginx.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in the Nginx directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and add a new server block here (example shown below).

```
server {
       # Change me to change my port number
       listen 8080;

       server_name example.com;

       root /var/www/example.com;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is multiple "server" stanzas, each with a different port. You may want to read more into the [documentation here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Example:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    root         /var/www/port80/
}

server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  *.example.org;
    root         /var/www/port81/
}
```

You can use the same server_name, serving the "different" content appropriately within each one. If you want to have the same server_name and root, but multiple ports, another solution would be this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 81;
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: hi this is my code to set new port or new server block in etc/nginx/sitesavailable/default

server {
 listen 81;

 root  /var/www/html;

 location /ocs/ {
               alias /var/www/html/ocs/;
                try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /ocs/index.html;
        }
}

Comment: @VineethA Can you tell me what is not working? I think I answered your question, now you should just use one of the methods and do what do you want to do.

Comment: this is my code  server {
                                          listen 81;

                                          root  /var/www/html;

                                          location /ocs/ {
                                                 alias /var/www/html/ocs/;
                                                 try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /ocs/index.html;
                                                   }
}